# php imap how to search unread and also sort them by date?

Tags: php, imap

Is it possible to get the unread messages and also sort them messages by date ? I have

```
$messages = imap_search($imap,"UNSEEN");
  imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1);
```

but I'm wondering if it shouldn't be

```
  imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1);
$messages = imap_search($imap,"UNSEEN");
```

or something else ?

Comment: imap_sort($inbox, SORTARRIVAL, 0, NULL, 'UNSEEN');

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
$messages = imap_search($imap,"UNSEEN");
$sorted = array_reverse($messages);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a code which will help you:

```
$host = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';

// Connect to the pop3 email inbox belonging to $user
$con = imap_open("$host", $user, $pass) or die("Can't connect: " . imap_last_error());

// after some sleeping
if (!imap_ping($con)) {
    // do some stuff to reconnect
die("The user is no longer logged in.");
} else {
    echo ('Connection Successful !');
}

$MC = imap_check($con);

// Get the number of emails in inbox
$range = "1:".$MC->Nmsgs; 

// Retrieve the email details of all emails from inbox
$response = imap_fetch_overview($con,$range); 
$response = array_reverse($response);

// displays basic email info such as from, to, date, subject etc...
foreach ($response as $msg) {
    // extra filters to show records which are Unread/Not seen  
    if($msg->seen == "0"  && $msg->recent == "0"){
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($msg);
        echo '</pre><br>-----------------------------------------------------<br>';
    }
}
```

Eventually, you can put condition for date wise sorting or key wise sorting with `ksort` function

Answer (score 0):

If you use imap_sort you don't need to use imap_search, as imap_sort admits a parameter $search_criteria as well as imap_search. Let's say imap_sort is like imap_search, but you can also get the results ordered.

```
$messages = imap_sort($imap, SORTDATE, 1, SE_UID, 'UNSEEN');
```

Answer (score -1):

U r performing two different actions on the original set of data independently. One possible way is to take all the data from first command(search), store it in some variable and then implement your own sort functionality.