# php how to perform imap_search and then sort only results

Tags: php, imap, imap-open

How can I perform a imap_search an then sort the result by date ?

I've tried

```
$imap_ressource = imap_open($server, $user, $password)
$search = imap_search($imap_ressource, 'Subject blablabla'); // to search email with same subject
$sorted = imap_sort($search , SORTARRIVAL , 1); // ERROR : imap_sort wants $imap_ressource
```

So who can I search stuff and sort ONLY the result, not all emails ...

Thanks

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57689998/4205384) help?

Comment: @El_Vanja I try `imap_sort($imap_ressource, SORTDATE, 1, SE_UID, 'Subject blablabla');` but when I want to go trough the given array with imap_fetchbody I get "bad message number" :(

Comment: The `imap_sort` [documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imap-sort) says "*SE_UID - Return UIDs instead of sequence numbers*". Replace that flag with `0` if you want the numbers.

Comment: @El_Vanja Thanks ;) it worked :) can you post your comment as an answer